# Problem when scaling on X axis

Tags: modeling, scale

I am trying to scale the following selected area along the x axis, so that it goes wider and will allow me to develop the shoulder area

However when I do so, some of the vertices seem to go inwards rather than outwards (see red in second image), which is causing problems

Any ideas what I can do?

[image]

[image]

Many thanks
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some sort of mirroring applied: all your vertices on the left half of the mesh are just mirror images of the vertices on the right. Therefore, the median point of your selection is not at the middle of the mesh, because it only takes into account "real" vertices, the ones on the right. When you "Scale", your vertices will all move away from that point.

Make sure that your 3D cursor is somewhere on the middle plane (it looks like it already is), then select "*3D Cursor*" as your pivoting point:

[image]

Finally, you should be able to { <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, *move your mouse* } to scale.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're scaling about the median point of your vertices, which are mirrored in X. Change your transform Pivot Center to the 3D cursor (Having ensured it's centered).